# Cannot click or select inputs on IE 8 Form

Tags: internet-explorer-8, forms

So basically been working on this issue for far too long now and nothing I do seems to fix the issue.

Basically if you go to http://www.completeenergy.co.uk and click on the "Get a Quote" button then try to enter details into the form nothing happens. You can not click on the inputs and or select anything within the form. This seems to happen in both IE7 and IE8.

Any ideas as to why this would happen when all other browsers seem to be working fine?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I seem to have accidentally come across the culprit. There was some strange conflicting issues arising from using the jquery pngfix. I made it so only versions lower than IE 7 can use it and boom, it starts working again.

Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

not sure, but it worked fine for me in IE8. Do you have any toolbars installed?

Comment: No, its just the standard IE8 I believe. Could this be to do with what OS I am running?

Comment: No idea sorry. I'm on XP and just tried it again.  No problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

This common issue is usually due to a z-index bug in IE. Try giving the input relative positioning and assigning a higher z-index.

Answer (score 0):

I was clicking on a form on a company intranet web site and nothing was happening.

Intranet defaults IE into compatibility mode, so the form was broken.

You can force edge compatibility in your browser or [with HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449286/force-ie-compatibility-mode-off-using-tags) and IE behave like modern browsers.