# Force IE compatibility mode off using tags

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I am doing work for a client who forces compatibility mode on all intranet sites. I was wondering if there is a tag I can put into my HTML that forces compatibility mode off.

Comment: I think that the answer you are looking for is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014666/force-ie8-into-ie7-compatiblity-mode

Comment: Actually I was looking for the exact opposite, who sets their standard to compatability mode, thats just insane.

Comment: Bad javascript on a legacy app that crashes on anything other than IE7, that's who sets their standard to compatibility.

One day, we'll get around to replacing it...

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge

Comment: @petethepagan-gerbil did you get around to replacing it? :P

Comment: @icedwater I left the company over 6 years ago :) We made small improvements to remove the issues whenever we had a change in the same area, but tech debt was never prioritised there. Don't know if it ever got fixed in the end.

Answer (score 547, accepted):

[There is the "edge" mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/cc817574.aspx).

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <title>My Web Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Content goes here.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

From the linked MSDN page:

> Edge mode tells Windows Internet Explorer to display content in the highest mode available, which actually breaks the “lock-in” paradigm. With Internet Explorer 8, this is equivalent to IE8 mode. If a (hypothetical) future release of Internet Explorer supported a higher compatibility mode, pages set to Edge mode would appear in the highest mode supported by that version; however, those same pages would still appear in IE8 mode when viewed with Internet Explorer 8.

However, "edge" mode is not encouraged in production use:

> It is recommended that Web developers restrict their use of Edge mode to test pages and other non-production uses because of the possible unexpected results of rendering page content in future versions of Windows Internet Explorer.

I honestly don't entirely understand why. But according to this, the best way to go at the moment is using `IE=8`.

Comment: This is actually good to use with Chrome Frame plugin. It removes the "compatibility" button from IE. I'v had issues where I want to use Chrome frame with IE8 and below but then someone using IE9 has the compatibility button set on as default and they end up being forced to install Google Chrome Frame when they don't need it.

Comment: As of 8/6/2012 Microsoft appears to be using `IE=10` on their own sites.  If you've tested your site in IE10 (preview version), it's safe to use this; otherwise, you may want to stick to `IE=9` for now.

Comment: I have found that this does NOT work if the user (or the sysadmin) has turned on compatibility mode as a default by going to `Tools->Compatibility View Settings`, and checking Display all websites in Compatibility View.  To fix the problem, I have to return the header in the HTTP response: `X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge`

Comment: +1 to speedplane - IE10 compatibility mode is ON by default for intranet sites - UGH...thanks for the find!

Comment: Word of advice for those who find this answer, but are unable to get it to work for them. The compatability meta tag *MUST* be the first meta tag, and there can be NO IE conditional statements before the tag. More: http://tesmond.blogspot.com/2011/10/ie9-intranet-compatibility-mode-in.html

Comment: Thank you Chris! I was struggling with this for 30 minutes when I finally read your comment. I didn't have it first.

Comment: @speedplane how exactly do you return the header in the HTTP response? I'm note sure how to do that.

Comment: @Sumit it depends what type of server/stack you are using.  If php, try googling, how to return HTTP headers in php.  If django, try how to return HTTP headers in django... etc.

Comment: Note, this does not force IE11 in enterprise mode (IE8 compat) into any different rendering modes. IE11 in compatibility mode is indeed forced to upscale.

Comment: Any update if Edge mode is still not recommended for production use?

Comment: it'd surprise me that it would not be recommended as there is no newer IE coming out anymore..

Comment: Microsoft web site is using `content="IE=edge"` now, so it must be recommended now!

Answer (score 95):

After many hours troubleshooting this stuff... Here are some quick highlights that helped us from the `X-UA-Compatible` docs:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(VS.85).aspx#ctl00_contentContainer_ctl16

Using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content=" _______  " />`

- The *Standard User Agent* modes (the non-emulate ones) ignore `<!DOCTYPE>` directives in your page and render based on the standards supported by that version of IE (e.g., `IE=8` will better obey table border spacing and some pseudo selectors than `IE=7`).
- Whereas, the *Emulate* modes tell IE to follow any `<!DOCTYPE>` directives in your page, rendering standards mode based the version you choose and quirks mode based on `IE=5`
- Possible values for the `content` attribute are:

  `content="IE=5"`

  `content="IE=7"`

  `content="IE=EmulateIE7"`

  `content="IE=8"`

  `content="IE=EmulateIE8"`

  `content="IE=9"`

  `content="IE=EmulateIE9"`

  `content="IE=edge"`

Answer (score 68):

If you're working with a page in the Intranet Zone, you may find that IE9 no matter what you do, is going into IE7 Compat mode.

This is due to the setting within IE Compatibility settings which says that all Intranet sites should run in compatibility mode. You can untick this via a group policy (or just plain unticking it in IE), or you can set the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

This works (as detailed in other answers), but may not initially appear so: **it needs to come before the stylesheets are declared**. If you don't, it is ignored.

Comment: thanks for the warning about the stylesheet, this was causing problems and i know the reason now!

Comment: Yep, initially mugged by placement. Thanks for adding this.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful.  They have a GPO that's setting the effective IE level at 7 even though IE 11 is installed.  This saved me from having to put some shims in the site to get the js to work.

Answer (score 30):

I believe this will do the trick:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Answer (score 30):

As suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3547611/130614) to a related question, "edge" mode can be set in the Web.Config file. This will make it apply to all HTML returned from the application without the need to insert it into individual pages:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This same step can also be accomplished by [modifying the "HTTP Response Headers" using IIS Manager](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders) for the IIS server, entire website, or specific applications.

Answer (score 20):

The meta tag solution wasn't working for us but setting it in the response header did:

```
header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1');
```

Comment: +1 for the 'chrome=1'; I never knew about that. For what it's worth, changing it to IE=10 cleared up a number of rendering issues on my site that IE=edge had no affect on.

Comment: Explanation of the `chrome=1` property, http://stackoverflow.com/a/22059516/368691. Bare in mind that Chrome Frame has been retired. http://blog.chromium.org/2013/06/retiring-chrome-frame.html

Comment: see comments on other answers...  I have found that this does NOT work if the user (or the sysadmin) has turned on compatibility mode as a default by going to Tools->Compatibility View Settings, and checking Display all websites in Compatibility View.  speedplane Apr 19 '13 at 11:29 
7 
 
The compatability meta tag MUST be the first meta tag, and there can be NO IE conditional statements before the tag. More: tesmond.blogspot.com/2011/10/… – Chris Sobolewski Aug 19 '13 at 20:23

Comment: I tried to put it on the first line in layout page. It does not work,  Stu mentioned changing IIS HTTP Response Headers. I tried. I restarted the app pool. I inspect more. This is page is nesting under other page. The other page does have another meta. This is the production website. So many people are accessing this page. putting this tag on top is mission impossible. Any other solution or I am screw

Answer (score 11):

IE8 defaults to standards mode for the intERnet and quirks mode for the intRAnet.
The HTML meta tag is ignored if you have the doctype set to xhtml transitional.
The solution is to add an HTTP header in code.
This worked for us.
Now our intranet site is forcing IE8 to render the app in standards mode.

Added to PageInit of the base page class (ASP.net C#):

```
Response.AddHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=EmulateIE8");
```

reference:
http://ilia.ws/archives/196-IE8-X-UA-Compatible-Rant.html

Answer (score 10):

Just a few more notes on this topic based on my recent experiences.  The university I work for issues laptops with IE 8 set to compatibility mode for all Intranet Sites.  I tried adding the meta tag to disable this mode for pages being served up by my site but IE consistently ignored this tag.  As Lance mentioned in his post, adding a response header fixed this issue.  This is how I set the header based on the HTML5 boilerplate method:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge,chrome=1"
  # mod_headers can't match by content-type, but we don't want to send this header on *everything*...
  <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|crx|css|eot|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|m4a|m4v|manifest|mp4|oex|oga|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|safariextz|svg|svgz|ttf|vcf|webm|webp|woff|xml|xpi)$">
    Header unset X-UA-Compatible
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

In order for this header to actually be sent, you have to make sure you have mod_headers turned on in Apache.  If you want to make sure you have this mod turned on, put this in a page that can run php:

```
<pre>
<?php
    print_r(apache_get_modules());
?>
</pre>
```

Comment: The .htaccess method worked for me, in IE8+ It removed the compatibility button (a.k.a Enemy No. 1) and forces IE8 to avoid using compatibility mode. Related: The meta tag alternative only seems to work under certain conditions (IE Voodoo) on various computers.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the setting within IE Compatibility settings which says that all Intranet sites should run in compatibility mode. You can untick this via a group policy (or just plain unticking it in IE), or you can set the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

Apparently it is not possible to change the compatibility view settings as a group policy but it is something that can perhaps be changed in the registry, this meta tag works fine for me, I had to make the required attribute work as part of a html form, it worked in chrome and firefox but not IE.

Here is a nice visual of what browsers support each individual html 5 element.

http://html5readiness.com/

Notice the one common denominator Google Chrome, it supports everything. Hope this is of help

Comment: Looks like Firefox and IE 10 now support everything as well. Chart doesn't make that as clear as it does for Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the server, the most reliable way of doing this is to do it on the server itself, in IIS. Go in to IIS HTTP Response Headers.  Add 
Name: X-UA-Compatible
Value: IE=edge
This will override your browser and your code.

Comment: This resets on new deployment to IIS if set at the website level

Answer (score 0):

Insert 
as the very first item under the  tag.

This forces IE to render the page in the physical version of IE, and it ignores the Browser "Mode setting". This can be set in the developer tools, try changing it to a older version of IE to test, this should be ignored and the page should look exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want each individual web page to load the chosen content and are using asp.net. Just apply it as the first tag under the heading tag in Views>shared>Layout.cshtml

just a tip