# prevent IE9 from entering compatibility view

Tags: internet-explorer-9, detect, ie-compatibility-mode

I am writing for IE9.

Sometimes I see that the option Tools ➝ Compatibility View is automatically checked (which I don’t want it to be, because I must unmark it from time to time).

The following piece of code pops up when the above compatibility view option is checked:

```html
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
        <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode">
            <img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." />
        </a>
    </div>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

How can I prevent this action from happening again and again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: I founded an answer on.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348959/how-to-disable-compatibility-view-in-ie.


Since, I have IE9 - I shall try the other solution.

Thanks, anyway.