# IE8 display differently on test server and localhost

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ext.net

I have built a website using ext.net and it displays normally in chrome, firefox and ie when it is on localhost. However, when I run the site on a local test server, it gets visually changed.

Here it is running on localhost:
[image: Local]
And here on the test server:
[image: Server]

Does anyone know why this happens to the buttons and why these scroll bars appear?

Thank you!

**UPDATE: If i enable compatibility mode, it looks like it does on the server side. Is there a way to disable server side compatibility mode?**
 [image: compatibility mode]

Comment: Note the torn-page icon in the first screen shot (http://www.seguetech.com/blog/2014/03/07/Internet-explorer-compatibility-mode)

Comment: @AlexK. that is to show compatibility mode. It is currently disabled.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-browser see this

Comment: @StaticVariable if it is an issue with cross-browser, then why does it display fine on localhost?

Comment: @AlexK. you are right, that does have something to do with it... Do you know how to disable compatibility mode from running on the server?

Comment: you may have different css ? have you cross checked ?

Comment: @NullPoiиteя when the page is viewed locally in compatibility mode or on the server it displays the incorrect way. However, not in compatibility mode on localhost displays it properly. That means it wont be the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the comments of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348959/how-to-disable-compatibility-view-in-ie).

> if the site is hosted on what Microsoft considers to be "Intranet" you're screwed, it will still display in Compatibility View. Only way to override that is to uncheck "Display Intranet sites in Compatibility View" checkbox in Tools - Compatibility View settings. That default setting in IE8+ really stinks.

My compatibility view was enabled.