# Disable IE 11 compatibility mode code is not working

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11, meta, compatibility-mode

I read from all over the internet that to disable IE 11 compatibility mode is just put a snippet of code:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
```

just directly under `<head>` tag. But when I tested it in IE 11 with compatibility mode (document mode) set to IE 7, the page still breaks. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Do you have "Display Intranet sites in Compatibility View" checked in tools? If IE thinks you're on the intranet, it will ignore this line regardless according to comment on top answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348959/how-to-disable-compatibility-view-in-ie

Comment: @dwreck08 I use hosts file to redirect a seemingly ordinary internet address ex:`www.example.org/index.html` to localhost. Is that counted as accessing local intranet too by IE?

Comment: @dwreck08 the "Display Intranet sites in Compatibility View" is checked by the way.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you can try unchecking in case IE thinks it is intranet. Also, be sure your doctype is set to `<!doctype html>`.