# Quirks mode is chosen by default

Tags: internet-explorer, drupal, drop-down-menu

Internet explorer automatically switches to "Quirks mode" when a web page is opened
afresh. Because of this, the menu (nice-menu in drupal) is broken and there are no child elements for the parent menu.

The doctype I use is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

But,when I set the "Document Mode" standards to "IE 8 or IE 7 standards" the menu works fine.

Can anybody please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult, without source to tell you why quirks mode is being selected. Honestly even with source it is a bit of a crap shoot. You can force IE into a specific mode by setting the X-UA-Compatible header or metatag. Take a look at brandonjp's answer on [Force IE compatibility mode off using tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449286/force-ie-compatibility-mode-off-in-ie-using-tags) for some examples.

Ideally, though, you should fix the code which is triggering quirks mode.