# Properly display/account for IE's Intranet compatibility in ASP MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, iis, intranet

My company currently uses IE as their standard browser (I know...). This is causing an issue with an ASP MVC site we just released as most IE browsers are set to enable "intranet compatibility moide." This causes the display of some of the elements to be quite a bit off. Since it would be very difficult to instruct all of our employees on how to turn this off, is there a way to compensate for it in the code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518256/override-intranet-compatibility-mode-ie8 this should help

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449286/force-ie-compatibility-mode-off-in-ie-using-tags

Comment: +1 for `(I know...)`. But your question is a dupe.

Comment: Great, thanks guys. Can I close this or does a mod have to?