# Html file works locally on IE, but not on server. Works fine for Opera, Chrome, Safari and Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Basically, as the title states, the file works locally, but not when uploaded to a server.

Here's a live working version: [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/guisasso/WKjT8/)

Code extracted from http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/07/31/creating-content-tabs-with-pure-css/

*The divs are displaying right below their parent tab. That's ok, I just striped down the code to post the question.

**This is all in one file, there's no reference to any external files, so path problems should be ruled out.**

Thanks.

**Google Chrome**
[image: Google Chrome]

**IE Local**
[image: Local IE]

**IE when uploaded to webserver**
[image: IE online]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Pure CSS Tabs with Fade Animation Demo 1</title>

    <style type="text/css">
      body, html {
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
          font-weight: 100;
          background: #aadfeb;
          text-align: center;
          font-family: helvetica;
      }

      .tabs input[type=radio] {
          position: absolute;
          top: -9999px;
          left: -9999px;
      }
      .tabs {
        width: 650px;
        float: none;
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 75px auto;
      }
      .tabs li{
        float: left;
      }
      .tabs label {
          display: block;
          padding: 10px 20px;
          border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
          color: #08C;
          font-size: 24px;
          font-weight: normal;
          font-family: 'Roboto', helveti;
          background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
          cursor: pointer;
          position: relative;
          top: 3px;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
          -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
          -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
          transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
      }
      .tabs label:hover {
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
        top: 0;
      }

      [id^=tab]:checked + label {
        background: #ececec;
        border-bottom: 3px orange solid;
        color: black;
        top: 0;
      }

      [id^=tab]:checked ~ [id^=tab-content] {
          display: block;
      }
      .tab-content{
        z-index: 2;
        display: none;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 140%;
        padding-top: 10px;
        margin-top:10px;
        background: #ffffff;
        padding: 15px;
        color: black;
        position: absolute;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
        -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
        -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
        animation-duration: 0.5s;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="main">
            <ul class="tabs">
                <li>
                  <input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="tab1">
                  <label for="tab1">test 1</label>
                  <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2">
                  <label for="tab2">test 2</label>
                  <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
                    "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3">
                  <label for="tab3">test 3</label>
                  <div id="tab-content3" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
                    "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
                  </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can not reproduce your problem with my IE9 (on Win7). Both versions (local and on my Linux-Webspace) are fine in IE9. But they show the "broken" result from your third screenshot when I switch the IE to IE-compatibilty-mode or IE8-mode or IE7-mode.

Since you can the IE allows different settings for Internet, Intranet and Trusted Sites, I think you should have a look at these settings in your IE and reset them to the default settings.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449286/force-ie-compatibility-mode-off-in-ie-using-tags

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the answer.  @Arno, you are correct, I had previously clicked on that button some time in the past (since I never use IE) and had changed it to enable "compatibility view". Apparently that setting is stored. So I cleared it, and it worked. Christian thanks for that, it is also very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone that may have this issue, make sure your css files are actually .css and not .html

chrome seems to recognize .html as a stylesheet locally but it wont work once uploaded.

hope that helps!

Comment: But the question specifies that there is just a single file. No separate CSS file.