# IE8 proxy CSS compatibility

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, proxy

I create a site that uses some css properties, specifically `display: inline-block`.
The problem is, in IE8 when the proxy is enabled, the display page is loaded without the `display: inline-block` property.
When the proxy is disabled the display is OK.
The strange thing is, the browser didn't use proxy because the site is in local.

I don't know what the problem is,
have you an idea?

Comment: This sounds like the browser is going into compatibility mode, which is actually IE7. IE7 does not support `display: inline-block;` [This question should help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449286/force-ie-compatibility-mode-off-in-ie-using-tags) There are also ways to support an `inline-block` like element in <IE8 browser, but I don't believe in supporting them unless 100% necessary and I highly suggest just forincg ie-edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem here is related to the security Zone of the page (Intranet), which impacts whether Compatibility View is used. See Tools > Compatibility View Settings > Display Intranet sites in Compatibility view.

The security zone of the page is in turn impacted by the proxy configuration. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250483(v=vs.85).aspx for details.