# Why does my layout not extend to the bottom of the window when percentages or floats are used?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, google-chrome, extjs, sencha-architect

When I am using width in percentage or float for a Sencha ExtJS panel, then set the left position and width in scientific notation by Sencha ExtJS, the layout stops before the bottom of the window is reached.

See this problem screenshot:

[image: Please See here for Screenshot of this problem]

I'm using ExtJS with the VB.NET framework on Chrome v52.

Can you please provide solution for this problem?

Comment: Can you please put some code or make jsfiddle which help us to understand your code better.

Comment: I'm generated json (pageInfo) for sencha as dynamic . and shrink json with page. 
code for sencha render:

ss.onReady(function() {
    document.body.id = 'editpage';
    Ext.getBody().addCls('editPage');
    PageDef = new ss.PageDefination(pageInfo)
}); 

as per code i'm adding div width in percentage. and sencha added left position into scientific notation. like "left: 6.035654e+10px "

also please note that this issue introduce in only chrome version 52. working fine with chrome older version.

Comment: It is not compatable with chrome 52 is it ?

Comment: yes, it is not compatible with chrome 52. but working fine with chrome 37.

Comment: If that is the case place this <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />  and check. I am referring from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059060/is-it-still-valid-to-use-ie-edge-chrome-1

Comment: You can try something with meta tag,.

Comment: thank you very much for your valuable response. and i'll try some tags with meta tag.

Comment: I tried all meta tags, but still getting same problem. can you please provide some other solution ?

Comment: Where are you adding meta tag ?

Comment: i have added meta tag into head section.

Comment: Ok, Also make sure that There is no css and js part before meta tag. I will try get back to u with some other solution.

Comment: ya sure. thanks and i'll waiting for your  other solution.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in Sencha Fiddle? Is the problem still there in Chrome 53?

Comment: No, this is working fine with chrome 53 version, but still getting same problem in chrome 52. i think this is chrome version problem.

Comment: One solution for this problem is,update your browser from version 52 to version 53. and Sencha Extjs Working Fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the below function in ext-all-debug.js

```
beforeSetPosition: function (x, y, animate) {
    var pos, x0;

    //change start here
    x = parseInt(x);
    y = parseInt(y);
    //change end here        

    if (!x || Ext.isNumber(x)) {
        pos = { x: x, y : y, anim: animate };
    } else if (Ext.isNumber(x0 = x[0])) { 
        pos = { x : x0, y : x[1], anim: y };
    } else {
        pos = { x: x.x, y: x.y, anim: y }; 
    }

    pos.hasX = Ext.isNumber(pos.x);
    pos.hasY = Ext.isNumber(pos.y);

    
    this.x = pos.x;
    this.y = pos.y;

    return (pos.hasX || pos.hasY) ? pos : null;
},
```

instead of

```
beforeSetPosition: function (x, y, animate) {
    var pos, x0;
    
    if (!x || Ext.isNumber(x)) {
        pos = { x: x, y : y, anim: animate };
    } else if (Ext.isNumber(x0 = x[0])) { 
        pos = { x : x0, y : x[1], anim: y };
    } else {
        pos = { x: x.x, y: x.y, anim: y }; 
    }

    pos.hasX = Ext.isNumber(pos.x);
    pos.hasY = Ext.isNumber(pos.y);

    
    this.x = pos.x;
    this.y = pos.y;

    return (pos.hasX || pos.hasY) ? pos : null;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `parseInt` value of `x` and `y`. Otherwise you need to update your browser above 52 version of chrome.