# Issues with IE compatibility mode and bootstrap

Tags: wordpress

I have huge issue with Twitter Bootstrap and IE 9. Can I force IE 9 to turn off compatibility mode because my website is falling apart with compatibility mode turned on.
Any help? Thanks a lot.

http://tinyurl.com/k5ylsad

Answer (score 0):

Already answered at [Force IE compatibility mode off using tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449286/force-ie-compatibility-mode-off-in-ie-using-tags)

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Also, make sure this is the FIRST meta tag.

Comment: I tried that of course.That was first result i found on google. As you can see in my source code its first tag but again i have problems.