# How to prevent IE11 Compatibility Mode for Intranet Sites via Ruby-on-Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, x-ua-compatible

I am working on a project that the client only allows their employers to look at intranet site. Therefore, in my project IE11 defaults to compatibility mode for intranet sites. Meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` gets overwritten. How do we set the content="IE=edge" even on intranet sites?

Comment: Edit this as a question and post the answer as a real answer.

Answer (score 3):

After searching for an answer, my co-worker helped solved this problem in Ruby. I research why IE11 was ignoring:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

The setting for IE=Edge has to render on the response header. This post [Force IE compatibility mode off using tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449286/force-ie-compatibility-mode-off-in-ie-using-tags) helped lead to an answer.

In your project find your controller that sets up your headers. In our project it is application_controller.rb.

Add:

```
before_filter :set_default_headers

  def set_default_headers
    response.headers["X-UA-Compatible"] = "IE=edge"
  end
```

This will allow IE11 to view the page in Edge even when the site is rendering for intranet view.