# Internet Explorer 11 & Compatibility View window.open() issue

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I've been having this odd issue with Internet Explorer 11 (Win 7) and Compatibility View. What I'm trying to do is open a new window when the user clicks on a button. For some reason, if I test in Compatibility View, the new window actually opens in the same window as the requester (the one with the button). When not in Compatibility View, it works as normal.

When opening `loader.html` directly and clicking the button, the window opens accordingly. Also, I have to refresh that loader page to actually have any JS scripts fire...

I've tested the same situation in Internet Explorer 10 (Win 7), and `window.open()` is able to open a new window in *both* Compatibility View and regular standards.

**Testing page setup is as follows:**

- `home.html` — opens `iframe.html` inside a new window (using `window.open()`)
- `iframe.html` — opens `loader.html` inside it a iframe
- `loader.html` — opens `index.html` (using `window.open()`) on button click

**My testing code is as follows on `loader.html`:**

```
window.onload = function (){
    $('#course-launch').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open('index.html', '_blank', 'menubar=0, location=0, toolbar=0, scrollbars=1, resizable=1, width=1090, height=820'); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Sounds like what you want to do is [force IE compatibility mode off using tags](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3449286/901048)

Comment: @Blazemonger, Yes, that's what I essentially it. The system that we are implementing our product into has a group-policy set for `Compatibility View`. This was the only way that we could force off it off using `X-UA` tags. It works well on local test, and on their system in IE10. But, we're just having this issue with IE11 + Compatibility View and opening windows.