# Force the Web application to run in IE8 compatability mode

Tags: javascript, css, vb.net, internet-explorer-8

My Webapplication is VB.NET MVC.It is currently running fine in IE8.Now we are going to migrate to IE10.While viewing the Web application from IE10,lots of bugs were found.Our clients do not wants to view the site in compatability mode by selecting the option in IE 11.

```
Tools --->Campatability view settings
```

Can any one suggest any code by which we can force the application to run in IE8 comapatability mode.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff966528(v=vs.85).aspx),

You can add

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

In `head` tag of your html.

Further [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5096802/1577396).