# Disable Compatiblity-View in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: html, asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have a asp.net-application. Now, my asp.net-Page will always be loaded in CompatiblityView in IE10. How can I prevent this, that IE10 will use CompatiblityView for my page?
I have already added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />` but Internet Explorer is still use Compatiblity-Mode instead of normal IE10-Mode.
When I open other websites, they are loaded in normal IE10-Mode.

When I load for example `http://www.google.ch` it will use normal IE10-Mode:

[image]

When I load my page, IE will change to compatiblity-Mode:

[image]

I can I prevent IE10 changing to Compatiblity-Mode?

Comment: What does IE=Edge give you?

Comment: it gives me: Browsermode: IE10-Kompatiblitätsansicht, Documentmode: Standards

Comment: the other sites that work fine, are intranet or internet sites?

Comment: the other working sites are internet - my sites are intranet

Comment: Check the anser for this question and also read the comments:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449286/force-ie-compatibility-mode-off-using-tags.
Perhaps the intranet settings is by default to use compatability mode and the meta tag should be the first meta tag before others.