# Qt breaks WebBrowser control somehow (Ajax is not working)

Tags: qt, webbrowser-control, iwebbrowser2

`Windows 10`.

I have 2 applications using the same `C++` library which creates `WebBrowser` control (Internet Explorer based control). It does not use `Qt`, only `WinAPI`.

First application is raw `WinAPI` based `C++` application which *does not* use `Qt`.

A second one is `Qt 5.9.2` widgets based `C++` application.

In both applications I try to open the following URL: https://vi.infcdn.net/test.html.

The problem is that in my first app this web page works as expected. 
But in my `Qt` based app it *does not* work. `Ajax` is not working on it.

**Addition #1.** I've also tried `webbrowser` example from `Active Qt` examples folder. (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/activeqt-activeqt-webbrowser-example.html). It's not working here too.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: It will take a lot of time for me to extract the required code. But you can use code from example, provided with Qt.  Web Browser example. Please see my Addition #1. It has exactly the same problem. This web browser example uses the same Internet Explorer Active X control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was Internet Explorer compatibility mode.

Here is how to disable it:
[Force IE compatibility mode off using tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449286/force-ie-compatibility-mode-off-using-tags)