# IE Browser Mode vs Document Mode for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, internet-explorer, telerik

I have a .net web app that uses Telerik Reporting, and I'm having trouble running their new version on my intranet site. Even with the meta tag for IE edge set or set in web.config, this puts the document into IE11 mode, but compatibility mode still picks it up for being in the intranet zone.

It's getting a javascript error promise undefined, and works fine if I manually add the site to Trusted Sites on my local browser to get it out of intranet compatibility mode.

I've been reading that this is the document mode vs the browser mode, so this is running in IE11 document mode, but the browser mode is still whatever compatibility mode is trying to set it down to for intranet, which looks to be IE5 if I don't have the meta tag. I was also reading that the document mode should determine what javascript engine IE11 uses, not the browser mode, but maybe this isn't true? Telerik says they don't support compatibility view, so I've been trying to force it to 11/edge, but this browser mode is killing me. Any other suggesions?

I don't want to keep my site in trusted sites either because I also want Windows Authentication on but it's defaulted off, and even if I wanted to try to get them to push out a group policy change to all browsers, there are a bunch of other sites in trusted sites and I'm not sure if turning windows auth on for everything might cause other problems for other sites.

Here is a screenshot of the console showing the javascript error even though doc mode is 11.

[image]

Comment: How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3449338/1641941) answer? You add the `X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge` as first meta before any conditionals in html or response header?

Comment: Did that, it sets the document mode to IE11 but not browser mode.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't just set it in your dev tools under `emulation`? I wonder why sys admins would set the mode to IE5, nothing will work unless it's been unmaintained for over 10 years.

Comment: Maybe it depends on what IE sees in the code on how it chooses. I see one other intranet site/app without a meta tag it defaults to IE7, but this one it defaults down to IE5. Yes I have the meta tag set which brings it up to IE11, but still has the javascript error about promise, which like I said seems to be that the browser mode is still running in compatibility view even though document mode is IE11.