# Angular 6 - Running dist folder with lite-server on IE11 doesn't work

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular6, production-environment, lite-server

I am trying to run my Angular 6 dist folder on IE. It works perfectly in Chrome. IE shows title in the tab correctly but nothing on the page. I have the classlist.js and web-animations-js polyfills installed. The project works in dev but not prod. I ran ng build --prod --build-optimizer to create dist folder.

Comment: If you open the browsers developer tools, what error is displayed? You may need to refresh the page in order to see the error.

Comment: Dev tools in IE11 says "SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier" for each of these files: browser-sync-client.js, runtime.js, polyfills.js, and main.js

Comment: The issue is with compatibility mode on IE. Here's the fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449286/force-ie-compatibility-mode-off-using-tags

Answer (score -1):

Uncomment below polyfills in the polyfills.ts file then rebuild it will work.

```
* BROWSER POLYFILLS
*/
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/

import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int'; 
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';`
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! All of these are uncommented and it still doesn't work. It's a strange issue. It works fine in dev and on a localhost but when I try to use an external server it acts like it did before I installed and uncommented the polyfills.