# Angular6 app is not working on IE but working fine on other browsers. SCRIPT1002: Syntax error vendor.js (69467,1922)

Tags: angular

SCRIPT1002: Syntax error 
vendor.js (69467,1922)

When i run my app on IE browser it shows nothing and give above error.
Any help??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH6k6.jpg)

here is my angular version

```
+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.6.8
| +-- html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0
| | `-- pretty-error@2.1.1
| |   `-- renderkid@2.0.1
| |     `-- strip-ansi@3.0.1
| |       `-- ansi-regex@2.1.1  deduped
| `-- node-sass@4.9.0
|   +-- chalk@1.1.3
|   | `-- strip-ansi@3.0.1
|   |   `-- ansi-regex@2.1.1  deduped
|   +-- npmlog@4.1.2
|   | `-- gauge@2.7.4
|   |   +-- string-width@1.0.2
|   |   | `-- strip-ansi@3.0.1
|   |   |   `-- ansi-regex@2.1.1  deduped
|   |   `-- strip-ansi@3.0.1
|   |     `-- ansi-regex@2.1.1  deduped
|   `-- sass-graph@2.2.4
|     `-- yargs@7.1.0
|       `-- cliui@3.2.0
|         `-- strip-ansi@3.0.1
|           `-- ansi-regex@2.1.1  deduped
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@6.0.6
| `-- chokidar@1.7.0
|   `-- UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY fsevents@1.2.4
|     `-- UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY node-pre-gyp@0.10.0
|       `-- UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY npmlog@4.1.2
|         `-- UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY gauge@2.7.4
|           `-- UNMET DEPENDENCY strip-ansi@3.0.1
|             `-- UNMET DEPENDENCY ansi-regex@2.1.1
+-- ansi-regex@2.1.1
+-- protractor@5.3.2
| `-- chalk@1.1.3
|   +-- has-ansi@2.0.0
|   | `-- ansi-regex@2.1.1  deduped
|   `-- strip-ansi@3.0.1
|     `-- ansi-regex@2.1.1  deduped
+-- strip-ansi@3.0.1
| `-- ansi-regex@2.1.1  deduped
+-- tslint@5.9.1
| `-- babel-code-frame@6.26.0
|   `-- chalk@1.1.3
|     `-- strip-ansi@3.0.1
|       `-- ansi-regex@2.1.1  deduped
`-- webpack-dev-server@3.1.9
  +-- strip-ansi@3.0.1
  | `-- ansi-regex@2.1.1
  `-- yargs@12.0.2
    +-- cliui@4.1.0
    | +-- strip-ansi@4.0.0
    | | `-- ansi-regex@3.0.0
    | `-- wrap-ansi@2.1.0
    |   `-- strip-ansi@3.0.1
    |     `-- ansi-regex@2.1.1  deduped
    `-- string-width@2.1.1
      `-- strip-ansi@4.0.0
        `-- ansi-regex@3.0.0  deduped

npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: ansi-regex@2.1.1, required by strip-ansi@3.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include some compatibility JS files for internet explorer.  Check out the [official guide](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support)

There is also a `polyfills.ts` file in your project, check it out and uncomment what you need:

```
... uncomment from here
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
...
```

also, you you are developing for enterprise environment, you might need to turn off the Internet explorers default compatilibity modes as well, you can read more about that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449286/force-ie-compatibility-mode-off-using-tags/3449338#3449338)

Comment: hm... maybe your problem is related to this? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9310

Comment: npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: ansi-regex@2.1.1, required by strip-ansi@3.0.1cls

Comment: try to run a simple `ng i` command or `npm install`, what does that show you?

Comment: npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.12.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
up to date in 10.945s

Comment: these are not error messages, did the install solve anything? Also, I suggest following the insturctions: install the dependencies for bootstrap. Try `ng update` to fix some of the dependency - versioning as well - I hope this helps.

Comment: solved i am using ckeditor5 in my app it was giving this error