# How to dynamically add quirks mode meta-tags in ASP.NET Web Forms from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, meta-tags, quirks-mode

I've got an`.aspx` page like the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to set quirks mode meta tags in code behind of the page i.e. in `Page_load` using:

```cs
HtmlMeta _ContentTypeTag = new HtmlMeta()
{
    HttpEquiv = "Content-Type",
    Content = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
};

Page.Header.Controls.Add(_ContentTypeTag);

HtmlMeta _QuirksModeTag = new HtmlMeta()
{
    HttpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible",
    Content = "IE=EmulateIE8"
};

Page.Header.Controls.Add(_QuirksModeTag);
```

But when I see the page source, it **currently** outputs this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>My Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(Duration=0.0)">
    <meta name="MSThemeCompatible" content="no">
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Whereas, I'm **expecting** the output to be something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>My Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=EmulateIE8>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

What's the cause of this behavior and how I can fix it?

**UPDATE**

I've fixed this using `Response.AddHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=EmulateIE8");` instead. (Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8884419/11914067))

But, it'll still be good to know why the initial approach wasn't working.

Comment: What version of the .NET Framework are you using? .
Do you have other MetaHtml tags in your code or template?
I have done a test with 4.6.1 putting your code in Page_Load and obtaining the expected result between the <title> tags

Answer (score 0):

It's Too Simple, USe below code at code behind.

```
    Page.Title = "Meta title string here.."; 
    Page.MetaKeywords = "Meta keyword string here.."; 
    Page.MetaDescription = "Meta description string here..";
```