# Microsoft Edge Non-IE mode

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge, meta-tags

I have an angular app hosted on intranet. It automatically tries to run under IE mode when using Edge browser. I tried removing `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` from index.html but no luck. IE Mode configuration has been disabled at browser level so I am not able to change it using settings. However, I know there are some websites which automatically run as NON-IE mode so there seems to be some meta settings.

Is there any specific settings required to force it run as NON-IE mode?

Comment: Personnaly, it was a setting automatically set by my company. I had to go in windows registry to disable the auto-redirect to IE

Comment: I can change the registry but it will be impossible to change for all the users of the application.

Comment: The other option you have here is to set the HTTP header as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31617249/7243127. There is also a comment on that page that suggests that it worked when the option had been set company wide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meta tag will not cause the site to render using the IE-mode.

It looks like some group policies are applied by your company that is loading your site in the IE mode.

I suggest you type `edge://policy/` on the Edge browser address bar and press the Enter key.

It will show the list of applied policies.

If all intranet sites are loading in the IE-mode then the below policy may cause this result.

[Send all intranet sites to Internet Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#send-all-intranet-sites-to-internet-explorer)

If only some sites are loading in the IE-mode then it can be possible that your site is added to the Enterprise Mode site list.

[Configure the Enterprise Mode Site List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#configure-the-enterprise-mode-site-list)

If you don't want to load that site in the IE-mode then I suggest you contact the IT department of your company to remove that site from the Enterprise Mode site list.

To get more information regarding IE-mode policies, I suggest you refer to the [Configure IE mode policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-internet-explorer-integration).

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.